# MS Access SQL for Query looking for "SecondOfID"

Tags: sql, ms-access

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to run a query in MS Access similar to `FirstOF`, but instead of returning the 1st occurrence, I require the 2nd occurrence.  For example in the following table, I would like to return the second unique occurrence within the item column:

```
 - ID   Item  Color
 - 1    Hat   Red
 - 2    Hat   Orange
 - 3    Hat   Yellow
 - 4    Hat   Green
 - 5    Hat   Blue
 - 6    Scarf Purple
 - 7    Scarf Brown
 - 8    Pants Black
 - 9    Pants Grey
 - 10   Pants White
```

I would like the query to return:

```
 - ID   Item    Color
 - 2    Hat     Orange
 - 7    Scarf   Brown
 - 10   Pants   Grey
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit painful in MS-Access.  This may work in MS Access:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
              from (select top (2) t2.*
                    from t as t2
                    where t2.item = t.item
                    order by id
                   ) as t2
             );
```

Otherwise, the counting method also works:

```
select t.*
from t
where 2 = (select count(*)
           from t t2
           where t2.item = t.item and t2.id <= t.id
          );
```

This is much, much easier in other databases.  So if you have the opportunity to work with other databases, you might want to switch.